# Highcharts dim unselected bars color on hover

Tags: highcharts

I need to dim stacked column (Highcharts) unselected bars when I hover on a single bar.

Current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-percent/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

Comment: you are asking to show only hovered bar to be highlighted others to be dimmed isn't it?

Comment: Use a mouseover event http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.events.mouseOver . When the event fires, update the point/series color with point.update()/series.update() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.update

Comment: @morganfree could you please add an example of your solution as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @NairAthul yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing `alpha` parameter you can use `Highcharts.Color` object and method `brighten(Number: alpha)`.

Define series options as follows

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: 'percent',
    stickyTracking: false,
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: updateStackColor(0.2), // brighten / dim color
        mouseOut: updateStackColor(0) // recover original color
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Function for changing stack colors can be like this:

```
function updateStackColor(alpha) {
  return function() {
    const x = this.x
    const color = Highcharts.color
    const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors

    this.series.chart.series.forEach((series, i) => {
      series.data.forEach(point => {
        const basePointColor = color(colors[i])

        point.update({
          color: alpha === 0
            ? basePointColor.get() // set original color
            : point.x === x
              ? basePointColor.brighten(alpha).get() // brighten original color
              : basePointColor.brighten(-alpha).get() // dim orignal color
        }, false)
      })
    })

    this.series.chart.redraw(false)
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2f5n3ve3/

Comment: Thanks a lot @morganfree this is perfect!